# Indicator for proportional correlation?

Tags: correlation, chi-squared-test, proportion

The data shown in the graph below seems to be linearly correlated, but not proportional. How can I show that it is not proportionally correlated?

It seems so simple, but none of my ideas so far come close to satisfying:

- Fitting y' = m*x and then measuring the relative difference |y'-y| / y. However, the difference is actually quite low for this example (20%). It would only make sense if it would be compared to the correlation between y and a straight line.
- Fitting y' = m*x+b and using |b| as an indicator. But that just seems silly
- In an old stats.stackoverflow thread the usage of the Spearman coefficient was proposed. However, in my understanding this checks for monotonicity correlations and not proportionality - [Which test to use: hypothesis that a variable is proportional to another variable (not necessarily linear)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285925/which-test-to-use-hypothesis-that-a-variable-is-proportional-to-another-variabl)
- Google showed some rather recent papers such as "Proportionality: A Valid Alternative to Correlation for Relative Data", but those seem like an overkill.

Is there any simple indicator such as the Pearson correlation coefficient? Thanks very much in advance.

~Edit: A new idea was to use the p-values for m and b in a linear fit y=mx+b. If there is a linear correlation (Pearson) and the p-value for b is high, it seems to indicate proportional relation. However, if the p-value is low, it seems that I cannot infer anyhting. For example, assume the second, very noisy graph below, created using a quadratic function and a lot of noise. The p-values for m is 0, the p-value for b is 0.004. I understand it the way, that m is most likely nonzero, hence there is a linear correlation (?). However, the Pearson correlation coefficient is only 0.79, which indicates otherwise and aligns with the ground truth. Concluding, this does not seem to help. In summary, this does not seem to be an extremely helpful indicator for this situation either...

[image: linear, but not proportional correlation]

[image: Quadratic function plus noise]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are interested in proportionality then the simplest thing to do is to plot the logarithm of the two variables and conduct a regression on the logged data, using the model:

$$\log Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_0 \log X_i + \varepsilon_i.$$

When $\beta_1=1$ you have $\log Y = \beta_0 + \log X$, which can be written as $Y = \exp(\beta_0) \cdot X \propto X.$  Hence, proportionality occurs in the case where $\beta_1 = 1$.  So if you want to test the hypothesis of proportionality of your variables, all you need to do is fit this regression, and then do a T-test for this hypothesis using the estimated coefficient and its standard error.  This is just like the regular test in the regression output, expect that you want to test the null hypothesis $\beta_1=1$ instead of the null hypothesis $\beta_1=0$.